# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun/misc/Unsafe.allocateDBBMemory

Tags: nosuchmethoderror

Has anyone been able to compile JRuby on a s390x Linux system?  I am trying to use LogStash, which apparently requires JRuby, however SLES 11 has no JRuby repo included.

jar ant produces the following.

compile-annotation-binder:
    [javac] Compiling 18 source files to /home/user7/jruby-1.7.4/build/classes/jruby
    [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
    [javac] Note: /home/user7/jruby-1.7.4/src/org/jruby/util/CodegenUtils.java uses unchecked or     unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 1 warning

compile-jruby:
    [javac] Compiling 1395 source files to /home/user7/jruby-1.7.4/build/classes/jruby
    [javac] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun/misc/Unsafe.allocateDBBMemory(J)J
    [javac]     at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.(DirectByteBuffer.java:127)
    [javac]     at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:306)
    [javac]     at sun.misc.Perf.createLong(Native Method)
    [javac]     at sun.misc.PerfCounter.(PerfCounter.java:77)
    [javac]     at sun.misc.PerfCounter.newPerfCounter(PerfCounter.java:83)
    [javac]     at sun.misc.PerfCounter$CoreCounters.(PerfCounter.java:140)
    [javac]     at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    [javac]     at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:236)
    [javac]     at sun.misc.PerfCounter.getZipFileOpenTime(PerfCounter.java:194)
    [javac]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:230)
    [javac]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:159)
    [javac]     at java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:167)
    [javac]     at java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:104)
    [javac]     at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(URLClassPath.java:958)
    [javac]     at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.access$700(URLClassPath.java:826)
    [javac]     at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:909)
    [javac]     at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:899)
    [javac]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:280)
    [javac]     at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(URLClassPath.java:898)
    [javac]     at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.(URLClassPath.java:871)
    [javac]     at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.rtJarLoader(URLClassPath.java:596)
    [javac]     at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:546)
    [javac]     at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:536)
    [javac]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:280)
    [javac]     at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:535)
    [javac]     at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:498)
    [javac]     at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:324)
    [javac]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1157)
    [javac]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:314)
    [javac]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:594)
    [javac]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:743)
    [javac]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:711)
    [javac]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:735)
    [javac]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:711)
    [javac]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:325)
    [javac]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:690)
    [javac]     at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:494)

BUILD FAILED
/home/user7/jruby-1.7.4/build.xml:636: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/user7/jruby-1.7.4/build.xml:289: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 1 minute 37 seconds

```
Line 636 of build.xml
    <target name="jar" depends="init" description="Create the jruby.jar file. Used during dev.">
->        <antcall target="jar-jruby" inheritall="true"/>
    </target>

Line 289 of build.xml
  <javac destdir="${jruby.classes.dir}" fork="true"
               debug="true" source="${javac.version}" target="${javac.version}"
->               deprecation="true" encoding="UTF-8" includeantruntime="true" memorymaximumsize="${jruby.compile.memory}">
            <classpath refid="jruby.execute.classpath"/>
            <src path="${src.dir}"/>
            <exclude name="org/jruby/runtime/Constants.java"/>
```

java -version
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxz6470sr4fp1-20130325_01(SR4 FP1))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.6, JRE 1.7.0 Linux s390x-64 Compressed References 20130306_140761 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R26_Java726_SR4_FP1_20130306_1011_B140761
JIT  - r11.b03_20130131_32403ifx1
GC   - R26_Java726_SR4_FP1_20130306_1011_B140761_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20130306_140761)
JCL - 20130315_01 based on Oracle 7u13-b08

ant -version
Apache Ant version 1.7.1

Answer (score 0):

The operating system calls init() method and mapps to main method so please try to
check properly that you provided mapping in pro-gramme or not I can not see the prospective
mapping in java without main method pro-gramme also executing if you provide inside
static block or you you should check your mapping.